# How to access translation file different than the current locale?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Question seems simple, but I can't find the answer.

I need to access something that is in a translation file, but it is not the one I'm currently using.
Let's say I have two languages, lang-1 and lang-2.

The language is set to lang-1, so If I do

```
I18n.t('whatever.path.name')
```

I will get the lang-1 name. And I'm also needing the lang-2 name. I've tried:

```
I18n.t("lang-2.whatever.path.name")
```

but this, as expected, leads to "lang-1.lang-2.whatever.path.name", and ends up throwing out translation missing.

Also, is cross-language-accessing (I don't know how to call it) a good idea, or maybe this is really wrong, and I shouldn't do it?

Comment: It looks like a wrong idea. Why are you trying to do this?

Comment: I'm storing translated language names in translation, and I need to list all of those names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Locale" is the term here. You can specify another locale like this:

```
I18n.t('whatever.path.name', locale: 'lang-2')
```