# Laravel Blade: How to access string translations of a different locale from the current locale?

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I am a newbie to laravel. Please humour me. I am working on a website that can be used in two different languages. I have two files, `en.json` and `te.json`, in `resources/lang`:

```
// en.json
"language-text": "English"
```

```
// te.json
"language-text": "తెలుగు"
```

I need to make it obvious to the visitors that they can use the website in English and Telugu. So in the header in my blade, I have this bit of code to render the language links:

```
@foreach ($languages as $language)
    @if ($language->code == app()->getLocale())
        <a href={{url()->current()}}>{{ __('language-text') }}</a>
    @else
        <a href={{
                    str_replace(
                        '/'.app()->getLocale().'/',
                        '/'.$language->code.'/',
                        url()->current()
                    )
                }}>{{ __('language-text') }}</a>
    @endif
@endforeach
```

Output for the English language version:

```
<a href="mywebsite.com/en/mypage">English</a>
<a href="mywebsite.com/te/mypage">English</a>
```

Output for the Telugu language version:

```
<a href="mywebsite.com/en/mypage">తెలుగు</a>
<a href="mywebsite.com/te/mypage">తెలుగు</a>
```

Whereas I want it like:

```
<a href="mywebsite.com/en/mypage">English</a>
<a href="mywebsite.com/te/mypage">తెలుగు</a>
```

I need to access `language-text` across locales. Like I need to access `language-text` from `te.json` when the current locale is `en` and vice-versa. My laravel-illiterate-brain tells me that it should be simple enough. I have searched far and wide to no avail. [These](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38500707/how-to-access-translation-file-different-than-the-current-locale) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34526693/access-to-field-of-model-based-on-current-locale-in-blade-laravel) seemed promising but those answers simply flew over my head. Does there exist a simpler solution to this problem?

**How do you access the keys in `resources/lang/te.json` while the locale is `en` and vice-versa?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can pass locale as 3-rd parameter to `__()` function.

Like this:

```
{{ __('language-text', [], 'te') }}
{{ __('language-text', [], 'en') }}
```

This is not documented in Laravel docs, but you can check source code [here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/524b1b3b4d677285ae2148d5a3b10774c696f8d8/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php#L833).

Comment: Excellent answer, I can't believe this is not in the official docs